# C# - String to int[]

Tags: c#

I need to make function saying if input is int[] digits = {1,2,3,4} output should be {1,2,3,5} .. like + 1 output.

I made below functions but I really don't know what is wrong with my code..

I don't know why I get the output {49, 50, 51, 53} instead of {1,2,3,5}

```
public static int[] PlusOne(int[] digits) 
{ 
    double changedDigits = 0 ; 

    for (int i=0 ; i <= digits.Length -1 ; i ++ ){
       changedDigits += digits[i] * Math.Pow(10, digits.Length-i-1); 
    }

    string s = (changedDigits+1).ToString();  
    int[] result = new int[s.Length] ;

    for (int j = 0; j < s.Length ; j ++) {
        result[j] = Convert.ToInt32(s[j]); 
    }

    return result; 
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach(var item in PlusOne( new int[] {1,2,3,4}))
        Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: You want to change `{1,2,3,4}` to `{1,2,3,5}` ? means incrementing the last digit by one? Can you explain the logic of how to get the output you want?

Comment: then why you are using Math.Pow() method?

Comment: Try `changedDigits += (changedDigits * 10) + digits[i];`

Comment: You're trying to calculate a check digit? don't use a double, don't convert to a string, use mod (`%10`) and divide to extract base 10 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s[j]` is a `char`, which means that converting it to an integer gives you the "value" of the character - `1` happens to be `49`.

The simplest way to fix your code is to do `result[j] = Convert.ToInt32(s[j].ToString());` instead, but you have many more options too. This works as a simple solution to an exercise, but if you want to go further, a good start would be to do all the math on integers (no double) and not using string at all. All you need is multiplication, integer division and modulo (%). Or, you can implement an adder on top of the array without converting to an integer - which can be slower, but will allow you to work with arbitrarily long positive integers.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your problem, you just want to increment the last element of your array by 1.
This function can help acheiving that.

```
public static int[] PlusOne(int[] digits)
    {

        digits[digits.Length - 1] = digits[digits.Length - 1] + 1;
        return digits;
    }
```

Comment: Presumably, if the last digit is `9`, the result should be `0` and the previous index should be incremented. The values are supposed to be digits, after all.

Comment: The issue is with Convert.ToInt32
It is converting "1" char to its ASCII code and doing the same for everything.

If you find this useful, please revert.

Answer (score 0):

you are converting a char to int which gives you the characters code. In this case, because it is only digits, ASCII. Just subtract 48 from each int and you should be fine.
But as others have suggested, for longer arrays you should probably think about a different approach instead of using strings and use arrays with a carry check.